# Allow structured bindings for templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, specialization, structured-bindings

So I have a little class where I would like to add structured binding support.
However I cannot figure out how to specialize `std::tuple_element` and `std::tuple_size` with my templated class.
This is my attempt:

```
template<typename... Cmps>
struct CmpGroup
{
    std::array<void*, sizeof...(Cmps)> cmps;

    template<typename C>
    C& get()
    {
        constexpr int index = GetIndexInPack<C, Cmps...>::value;
        static_assert(index != -1);
        return *static_cast<C*>(index);
    }

    template<size_t I>
    auto& get()
    {
        static_assert(I < sizeof...(Cmps));
        using CmpType = typename GetTypeInPack<I, Cmps...>::type;
        return *static_cast<CmpType*>(cmps[I]);
    }
};

namespace std
{
    template<typename... Types>
    struct tuple_size<CmpGroup<Types...>> : public integral_constant<size_t, sizeof...(Types)>;

    template<std::size_t N, typename... Types>
    struct tuple_element<N, CmpGroup<Types...>> {
        //got this from: https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/structured-bindings/
        using type = decltype(std::declval<CmpGroup<Types...>>().template get<N>());
    };
}
```

(I have left out some implementation specific things for clarity, the full snippet can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/8whYLdnR) )

However this causes the tuple_size specialization to give a compile error: `error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before ';'`

Is it even possible to allow a templated class to have structured bindings or am I missing something?

Comment: A struct needs a body `{ }` even if it is empty.

Comment: @BoPersson holy shit I can't believe I missed that! I was looking at this code for hours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, my `tuple_size` specialization needed to have a body which I overlooked.

```
template<typename... Types>
struct tuple_size<CmpGroup<Types...>> : public integral_constant<size_t, sizeof...(Types)>{};
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^
```

Thanks @BoPersson for pointing that out!